# Rendering high quality image as textures in webgl

Tags: webgl

i am new to the concept of webgl. I have a webgl code where i use different images as textures onto different sides of the cube, but the images appear to be blur. I have tried out using various images with different resolutions but none seems to work. Worst part is am even not good at image processing. Anyone please help me on this issue. Can we programmatically maintain the clarity of image while projecting it onto sides of cube.

Thanks

Comment: blurriness is usually from upscaling. Downscaling would make the image "chunkier" (unless using mipmaps, which help smooth downscaling).

What resolution are your images, and how big are you drawing the cube?

Are you using webgl directly, or a framework (like three.js or Babylon.js)?

Comment: Am using webgl directly with no other libraries or framework. Images are of the resolution 512x512 or more, power of 2. i have created my canvas with height and width set to 100% in style sheet and the same width and height is used for my viewport. i have declared my cube and texture coordinates as follows

Comment: sorry the vertices are too long to be posted here. However my vertices range from -1 to 1 corresponding to the sides of cube and same is the case with my texture coordinates.

Comment: Can you show the blurry cube on a URL? or include some of the code?

Comment: These are my cube vertices -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
-1.0,  1.0,  1.0

-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
-1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

-1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
-1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

 -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
  -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
 -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
 -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

Comment: My Texture coordinates // Front face
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,

          // Back face
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,

          // Top face
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 1.0,

          // Bottom face
          1.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 1.0,
          0.0, 0.0,
          1.0, 0.0,

          // Right face
1.0, 0.0,
1.0, 1.0,
0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0,

// Left face
0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 0.0,
1.0, 1.0,
0.0, 1.0,
  
1.0, 0.0,
1.0, 1.0,
0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0,

Comment: and my cubeVertexIndices = [
            0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
            4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
            8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
            12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
            16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
            20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
        ];

Comment: function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  
        } catch (e) {
        }
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
        }
    }

Comment: var texturen = new Array();function initTexture(file,texturen) {
var anz = texturen.length;texturen[anz] = gl.createTexture();
texturen[anz].image = new Image();texturen[anz].image.onload = function() 
{
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[anz]);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texturen[anz].image);
 //For power of 2 images

Comment: gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);}
texturen[anz].image.src=file;
}

Comment: the above function is to initialize texture and my draw function contains following:--    gl.viewport(0,0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight); mat4.perspective(30, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0,pMatrix);  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexPositionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, worldVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer);

Comment: gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexIndexBuffer); i bind 6 textures one by one as follows          gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[0]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[1]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); later same statements remaining textures

Comment: am extremely sorry for the worst presentation of my code above, as i am writing the code locally there s no URL for that as well. Please help me out.

Comment: Is this solved?I have the same question.I'm using three.js
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313899/how-can-i-use-none-repeat-tiling-texture-in-three-js

Comment: yes this is solved, the issue was not with the upscaling or downscaling of the image, the issue was with the height and width set to my div tag containing the canvas