# how can i use none repeat tiling texture in three.js

Tags: three.js, tile

I am making a panorama like krpano.I want to know how can i use small images as a texture of one cube face?
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Skybox.html
This example uses 6 pics as texture of cube.Could i use many small tiles as each texture of cube face?

Comment: Krpano seems render the cube face as small pieces.Maybe it uses several mesh as one cube face.

Comment: yes you can use different textures for each face of the cube

Comment: moreover in case of sphere geometry , you could construct small spheres using different pi and theta values, texture them and arrange those to form a complete sphere.

Comment: Actually i'm a little curious,are you chinese?But i am.If so,can we talk in chinese or talk in qq or anything else?I thought maybe we were doing the same thing and i do have something to share with you.

Comment: And now i find the answer for the question.I mean using how about 4 pieces of pics to texture one cube face though it have some problem.But i think i will resolve it soon.In one word i change the cube geometry's vetices and faces and faceVertexUvs.Maybe i'll post it when finished.

Comment: Am indian. Yes please post once you finish it.

Comment: @DPH I made a example below and you may get something from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is making a new geometry,set your own vertices,faces that meet your demand and then set the faceVertexUvs and materialIndex to make it well textured.

```
  vertices.forEach(function(v){
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v[0],v[1],v[2]));});
 faces.forEach(function(v){
geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( v[0],v[1],v[2] ) );});
```

I have a example here:[multipleTexture](http://aboutqx.github.io/test/multipleTexture.html)

Also note that

> using textures whose sides are a power of two is ideal-
>   [webgl texture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Using_textures_in_WebGL#Non_power-of-two_textures)